# 422 Unprocessable Entity. Uploading multiple files UploadFiles FastAPI

Tags: python, file-upload, upload, fastapi

Returns the error "422 Unprocessable Entity". Here is my code and most likely it is related to downloading the file. Intentionally removed and simplified the entire code

```
`@app.post('/test/almost whole')
async def create_catch(catch: tag_shemas.CatchCreate, files: list[UploadFile],
                       user: User = Depends(current_user),
                       db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if not files:
        return {"message": "No upload file sent"}
    for file in files:
        if file.content_type != "image/jpeg":
            return {"message": 'incorrect file'}
    return crud.create_test(db=db, uploaded_file=files, id=user.id, catch=catch)

CRUD

def create_catch(db: Session, uploaded_file, id, catch: tag_shemas.CatchCreate):
    db_geo = models.Geo(coordinates_n=catch.coordinates_n, coordinates_e=catch.coordinates_e)
    db_description = models.Descriptions(description=catch.description, user_id=id)
    db.add_all([db_geo, db_description])
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_geo)
    db.refresh(db_description)

    db_tag = models.Tags(description_id=db_description.id, geo_id=db_geo.id, user_id=id)
    db.add(db_tag)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_tag)

    for file in uploaded_file:
        file_location = rf"C:\Users\v/{file.filename}"
        with open(file_location, 'wb+') as file_object:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, file_object)
            db_photo = models.Photos(tags_id=db_tag.id, description_id=db_description.id, photo_url=file_location)
            db.add(db_photo)
        db.commit()
    return {'OOOOOkkkk'}`
```

When I remove the part with the file upload, everything works fine. I can't figure out where the error is. Most likely something syntactic